# How to Compare nested Dictionaries and update missing items in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hai needs to compare two dictionaries. How to Find and update the missing items to the base dictionary.

```
language_1 = {"kannada" : {"lbl01":"kannada_File","lbl02":"kannada_accounts","lbl03":"kannada_Inventory","lbl04":"kannada_manufacture"},
          "english": {"lbl01": "File", "lbl02": "Accounts", "lbl03": "Inventory", "lbl04": "manufacture"}}
          

language = {"id"      : {"lbl01":"file"      ,"lbl02":"accounts"     ,"lbl03":"inventory"       ,"lbl04":"manufacture"},
            "english" : {"lbl01":"File"      ,"lbl02":"Accounts"     ,"lbl03":"Inventory"       ,"lbl04":"manufacture"},
            "tamil"   : {"lbl01":"கோப்பு"    ,"lbl02":"கணக்கியல்"   ,"lbl03":"சரக்கியல்"       ,"lbl04":"உற்ப்பத்தி"},
            "hindi"   : {"lbl01":"Hindi_File","lbl02":"Hindi_accounts","lbl03":"Hindi_Inventory","lbl04":"Hindi_manufacture"}}
```

For example "language" is my base dictionary. I want to check, whether the items in "langugae_1" is found in a base dictionary or not. If Not found, then add it into the base dictionary. In my case "kannada" is not found in my base dictionary, so add it into the base dictionary. How to resolve it?

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a simple question. the dictionary has the `.update()` function.

```
language.update(language_1)
```

or if you need to apply some filter-logic

```
language.update({k:v for k,v in language_1.items() if <some logic>})
```

[here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update) some example [and here](https://pythonguides.com/python-dictionary-update/)

If you need some sophisticated logic,  [dictdiffer](https://dictdiffer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can be a very useful pakcage

Answer (score 2):

Simple and understandable way.

```py
language_1 = {"kannada" : {"lbl01":"kannada_File","lbl02":"kannada_accounts","lbl03":"kannada_Inventory","lbl04":"kannada_manufacture"},
          "english": {"lbl01": "File", "lbl02": "Accounts", "lbl03": "Inventory", "lbl04": "manufacture"}}


language = {"id"      : {"lbl01":"file"      ,"lbl02":"accounts"     ,"lbl03":"inventory"       ,"lbl04":"manufacture"},
            "english" : {"lbl01":"File"      ,"lbl02":"Accounts"     ,"lbl03":"Inventory"       ,"lbl04":"manufacture"},
            "tamil"   : {"lbl01":"கோப்பு"    ,"lbl02":"கணக்கியல்"   ,"lbl03":"சரக்கியல்"       ,"lbl04":"உற்ப்பத்தி"},
            "hindi"   : {"lbl01":"Hindi_File","lbl02":"Hindi_accounts","lbl03":"Hindi_Inventory","lbl04":"Hindi_manufacture"}}

for a in language_1:
    if not any(language[b] == language_1[a] for b in language):
        count = list(language).count(a)
        if count:
            language[a+str(count)] = language_1[a]
        else:
            language[a] = language_1[a]

print(language)
```

I know a simple way is `language.update(language_1)` but If you want to check Every nested dictionary then use this.

### Means

```py
d = {'a':[1,2,3]}

full_d = {'a':[1,2]}

# Here full_d['a'] != d['a'], THen this make another key but with the serial number.

# OUTPUT

{'a':[1,2],'a1':[1,2,3]}
```

#### OR Try this (Suggested First One)

```
for a in language_1:
    if not any(language[b] == language_1[a] for b in language):
        count = list(language).count(a)
        if count == 1:
            language[a+str(count)] = language[a]
            del language[a]
        if count:
            language[a+str(count+1)] = language_1[a]
        else:
            language[a] = language_1[a]

print(language)
```

```py
d = {'a':[1,2,3]}

full_d = {'a':[1,2]}

# Here full_d['a'] != d['a'], THen this make another key but with the serial number.

# OUTPUT

{'a1':[1,2],'a2':[1,2,3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a simple answer:

```
language.update(language_1)
```

Comment: This will overwrite the existing values of language if keys are same

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt python dictionary method to do exactly the same
You can use [dict.update()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/dict/update.html) method to achieve this.

In your case.
First you need to copy your data from language_1 to some variable(If you want to keep language_1 intact)

```
temp = language_1.copy()
```

Then you can perform update

```
temp.update(language)
```

Copy the data to language variable

```
language = temp.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just simply assign it like this

```
for key in language_1.keys():
if key not in language.keys():
    language[key]=language_1[key]
```